# Flutter default white color value

Tags: android, flutter, colors

I thought the standard background of a flutter app was simple white (`Colors.white`). But when looking closely white **doesn't match** the actual standard background. See here:

[image].

*Left: default value; Right simple white*

It might be really hard to detect, but there is a slight difference, which might be more **prominent on other devices/screens**.

What is the standard white color for flutter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the default Scaffold background color (if you have a context):

```
Container(
  color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor
)
```

But default flutter Scaffold color is NOT

```
Colors.white
```

its

```
Colors.grey[50]
```

Answer (score 0):

On my device the Background colour is:

```
Colors.grey[50]
```

or Hex:

```
FAFAFAFF
```